# JUnit Error: "Failed to load ApplicationContext"

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, junit4, applicationcontext

Nothing seems to work

I'm trying to run simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class EmailServiceTest {
```

I've also tried:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class EmailServiceTest {
```

Along with a few different things in place of "location," such as "classpath" and "file."

The "ApplicationContext" is located:

```
src
    main
        webapp
            WEB-INF
                applicationContext.xml
```

But JUnit test still says: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: No, it says that *and provides a detailed error message*, such as saying which bean it was trying to find but couldn't. Post that message. In this case, it's likely because your `applicationContext.xml` isn't in either of those locations *on the classpath*. If you're new to Spring, I highly recommend going with Spring Boot and going with its conventions (including not using legacy XML) until you have more familiarity with Spring generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was solved after we realized our build file was missing information pertaining to testing. Information such as the "app.properties" and " applicationContext" were not being copied into the testing resources. So technically, none of these were on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

"Failed to load ApplicationContext" can happen due to other reasons. Go through the stacktrace and find the cause of this error.
In my case, I got this error because I had a typo in the application context xml file name.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:./src/main/resources/ApplicationContext.xml" })` after `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. and test.java file create at `/src/test/java/your-package-name`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify an application context location on the classpath. `src/main` is added to the classpath. Therefore, you need to specify only `webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` as follows: `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"})`.