# How should I load Spring's ApplicationContext without xml for unit-tests?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit, applicationcontext

I have a unit test like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void createTest() throws Exception {

         //... blah blah blah
```

This is failing because I'm unable to load my `userRepository` with `@Autowired`:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

I don't have an `applicationContext.xml` like [this would suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764218/junit-error-failed-to-load-applicationcontext).

My project structure looks something like this:

```
.
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── com
│   │       └── foo
│   │           └── bar
│   │               ├── Main.java
│   │               ├── models
│   │               │   └── User.java
│   │               └── repositories
│   │                   └── UserRepository.java
│   └── resources
│       ├── application.yaml
│       ├── public
│       └── templates
└── test
    └── java
        └── com
            └── foo
                └── bar
                    └── models
                        └── UserTest.java
```

This project heavily uses annotations. In my `Main` class, I have something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml"),
})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {
        UserRepository.class,
})
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

I'm using Gradle and I have these testing dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0'
```

**Question:**

Could someone please explain to me what's going on and what could be the possible causes and solutions to something like this?

Comment: Have you tried creating an `application.yml` in `src/test/resources`? Two comments on your code: Why do you need the `UserRepository` when testing the `User` pojo? --- I would suggest to rename package `com.foo.bar.repositories` to `com.foo.bar.repository`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Same error after copying `application.yaml` to `src/test/resources`. You're prob right about your other comments.

I noticed some other tests in there have things like `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` Should I do something like that?

Comment: Can you please add the full exception stack trace. Usually there should be a hint why Spring can instantiate your `UserRepository`

Answer (score 0):

You have to point out the components which will provide the interface implementations. In your case you can do something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={Main.class})
public class UserTest {
....}
```

**Or**

create configuration class in the test sources like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {
        UserRepository.class,
})
public class PersistenceConfiguration {
}
```

Most probably you have to create a configuration class like below too:

```
@Configuration
@@EntityScan(basePackage={"packages.where.you.put.your.entity.classes"})
public class EntityConfiguration {}
```

after that, use that class in the test like below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={PersistenceConfiguration.class, EntityConfiguraiton.class})
public class UserTest {
 ....}
```